# YM chat integration in react native - bot does not trigger journey based on journey slug

Tags: javascript, react-native

We are trying to trigger a specific journey based on journey slug but out bot cannot pick the specific journey. though bot is getting called it does not go to specific chat

Tried sending botid, journeyslug and device token to YMchat sdk.